# how to thymeleaf select row value parameter jquery function?

Tags: thymeleaf

How can I send the selected line value?

```
<select th:onchange="changes(this.getAttribute('data-test'))">
  <option th:each="list : ${allList}"
          th:value="${list?.number}" 
          th:text="${list?.name}"
          th:data-test="${list?.test}">
  </option>
</select>
```

onchange(list.test) value parameter ....

Answer (score 0):

This should work (in your case, `this` refers to the select object, and not an `option`).

```
<select th:onchange="changes(this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset.test)">
  <option th:each="list : ${allList}"
          th:value="${list?.number}" 
          th:text="${list?.name}"
          th:data-test="${list?.test}">
  </option>
</select>
```